# QSettings restore causes app to freeze on show() if missing QDockwidget

Tags: windows, qt, qdockwidget, qsettings

I have a Qt application that load .dlls which in turn will add `QDockwidget` widgets to a `QMainWindow`.  To maintain the size and geometry I am saving them in `QMainWindow`

```
    QSettings settings;
    settings.setValue("MainWindow/geometry", saveGeometry());
    settings.setValue("MainWindow/windowState", saveState());
```

and on startup I read back the settings

```
    QSettings settings;
    restoreState(settings.value("MainWindow/windowState").toByteArray());
    restoreGeometry(settings.value("MainWindow/geometry").toByteArray());
```

Just before calling `show()`.

When I run the app, close it, then delete one of the dlls (effectively removing a `QDockwidget` that previously loaded at start up), the app will freeze on the `show()` call in `QMainWindow`.  I can get the application to start up properly by deleting the registry folder (I'm in Windows) `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\MyCompany\MyApplication\MainWindow`, but I lose all the other information stored there.

What I want is for the UI to come up as if the missing `QDockWidget` is hidden and can never be restored, not this nonsense of destroying all of the geometry and state information.

Has anyone seen this problem? Solved it even!?! I would be grateful for any hints, tips, or work-arounds!

Cheers

Comment: If you know which dock widget will be removed, you can close it before saving the state of the main window, so that the state will not contain removed dock widget's settings at all.

Comment: Why don't you check the availability of the dlls with QLibrary and if the corresponding libs are not available, you do not read things in from QSettings respectively?

Comment: The problem is that it is an open  interface and we can't know what will be loaded. So we don't know the dlls or the widget names